# List all properties contributed by BOM to gradle 5

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, maven-bom

Is there a way to list all properties contributed by a given bom to gradle using `gradlew`/`gradle`

Suppose I have the following build script

```
  dependencies {
    //*** bill of materials
    springBom platform("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.1.2.RELEASE")
  }
```

I would like to list all properties that are available as part of the bom, how can I do that?

I know it contributes a property called `micrometer.version` because the source says so

Ref: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-dependencies/pom.xml

Answer (score 3):

`io.spring.dependency-management`plugin makes all of the properties from imported BOMs [available](https://docs.spring.io/dependency-management-plugin/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html5/#accessing-properties) for use in your Gradle build.

So, basically, you can write your custom gradle task to print all of them.

```
tasks.register("spring-boot-properties") { 
    group = 'Introspection'
    description = 'Print properties from all BOMs'
    doLast { 
        println dependencyManagement.importedProperties
    }
}
```

Then just execute the task: `./gradlew spring-boot-properties`

Comment: Thanks. I know spring provides its own plugin. But I dont want to use additional plugins. I would like to use newer BOM features of gradle 5.0+

Comment: Actually, if you are using Spring Boot BOMs then you are using dependency-management plugin. So no additional plugins are actually implied. However, if I underastand right, you are looking for build-in task for displaying all BOMs properties. All built-in tasks can be listed using `./gradlew tasks` command. Under `Help tasks` you can find some usefull ones (e.g. `buildEnvironment`, `dependencies` etc.). I think, the closest to what you want is `properties` task, but it doesn't allow to get properties from BOM. Hopefully, this clarifies something.

Comment: Gradle 5 comes with its own BOM resolver. This is a complete replacement for spring `dependency-management` plugin

Answer (score 2):

Maven BOM support in Gradle does not expose that information. The properties are effectively inlined when parsing the POM hierarchy and thus no longer available in the dependency metadata format of Gradle.

As commented in the other answer, using the Spring `dependency-management-plugin` gives you access to these values.

Comment: Are there any plans to expose this information in the future?